# JQuery Mobile select menu is blank in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I have an app built with jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap Build and have recently noticed that the select menu items appear blank in Android 5.0 (lollipop).  They still appear normally in older Android versions and in the browser.

I would like to keep the styling used by jQuery Mobile, so switching to something like Select2 is not ideal.

I've tried adding `data-native-menu="true"` to the select menu, but that had absolutely no effect.  Is there some other way to force the native Android select list pop-up to be used?

Here's the code for my menu:

```
<select data-theme="b" name="countrySelect" id="countrySelect" data-native-menu="true">
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="CA">Canada</option>
        <option value="AU">Australia</option>
</select>
```